# How do I add a member into a GroupOfNames using go-ldap module?

Tags: go, ldap

The demand is to add an user of ObjectType `PosixAccount` into a group of ObjectType `groupOfNames` by adding it as value of attribute `member`.

I'm using [go-ldap](https://gopkg.in/ldap.v2) module to accomplish that.

Here below is a sample of the code I've written to complete this demand:

```golang
    package main

    import (

    "log"

    "github.com/go-ldap/ldap"
    )
    
    func main() {

        // connection code here

        PutOnGroup := ldap.NewModifyRequest("cn=0000-00000-00000f-abc123-app- 
        session,ou=servicesAccounts,dc=example,dc=com", []ldap.Control{})
        PutOnGroup.Replace("member", []string{"cn=1000000-fa00-de00-ac00-f00c00e00d00b00- 
        ingestion-svc"})

        err = conn.Modify(PutOnGroup)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error putting user on group %v: %v", PutOnGroup, err)
        }
    }
```

The thing is by doing that I just replace the user which is already member's attribute of group.

I'd like to input this member into the group alongside with members which is already there.

How could I do that?

---

*I'm not used to ask questions in StackOverflow so if my question is lacking of details I'm looking foward to provide more information.*

Answer (score 2):

This problem was solved by changing the `ldap.NewModifyRequest`'s function `Replace` to `Add`.

```golang
     PutOnGroup := ldap.NewModifyRequest("cn=0000-00000-00000f-abc123-app- 
        session,ou=servicesAccounts,dc=example,dc=com", []ldap.Control{})
     PutOnGroup.Add("member", []string{"cn=1000000-fa00-de00-ac00-f00c00e00d00b00- 
        ingestion-svc"})
```